# Ito's isometry vs statistics for the same problem

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

The objective is an explicit calculation of 
$\mathbb{E}\left[ {\left( {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{at}}dW(t)} } \right)\left( {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{bt}}dW(t)} } \right)} \right]$. I'm trying to compare two approaches to this: via Ito's isometry and a 'statistical' approach.

Ito's isometry quite clearly says that

$\mathbb{E}\left[ {\left( {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{at}}dW(t)} } \right)\left( {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{bt}}dW(t)} } \right)} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{(a + b)t}}dt} } \right] = \frac{{{e^{(a + b)T}} - 1}}{{a + b}}$.
Let's call this **result 1**.

However, because 
$\int\limits_0^T {f(t)dW(t)} \sim N\left( {0,\int\limits_0^T {{f^2}(t)dt} } \right)$, for a deterministic function $f$, I can also write the initial problem as
$\mathbb{E}\left[ {\left( {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{at}}dW(t)} } \right)\left( {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{bt}}dW(t)} } \right)} \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ {\sqrt {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{2at}}} } \varepsilon \sqrt {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{2bt}}} } \varepsilon } \right] = \sqrt {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{2at}}} } \sqrt {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{2bt}}} } \mathbb{E}\left[ {{\varepsilon ^2}} \right]$,
where $\varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$. This implies $\mathbb{E}\left[ {{\varepsilon ^2}} \right] = 1$ (as ${\varepsilon ^2}$ is chi-squared with one d.f.). After explicit integration this gives
$\mathbb{E}\left[ {\left( {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{at}}dW(t)} } \right)\left( {\int\limits_0^T {{e^{bt}}dW(t)} } \right)} \right] = \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {\frac{{({e^{2aT}} - 1)({e^{2bT}} - 1)}}{{ab}}}$.
This is **result 2**.

Comparing **result 1** and **result 2** I get 
$\frac{{{e^{(a + b)T}} - 1}}{{a + b}} \ne \frac{1}{2}\sqrt {\frac{{({e^{2aT}} - 1)({e^{2bT}} - 1)}}{{ab}}} $, unless $a=b$. When substituting some reasonably small $a  \ne b$ and some $T$, then both results are numerically 'close' yet still not similar.

My questions are:

- Which of the results is exact?
- Why each result is different, although hypothetically correct in its own world?

My intuition about the difference points towards the nature of the exponential integrand. Maybe it does not satisfy some technical condition needed by Ito's isometry or by the other approach?

Answer (score 1):

The first calculation (via Itô's isometry) is correct and the "statistical" approach is not.

If $X \sim N(0,\sigma_1^2)$, $Y \sim N(0,\sigma_2^2)$ are two normal random variables, then the covariance

$$\mathbb{E}(X Y)$$

depends on the **joint** distribution of $X$ and $Y$. For instance if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, then

$$\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X) \mathbb{E}(Y)=0.$$

In contrast, if we choose $Y=X$, then

$$\mathbb{E}(X Y) = \mathbb{E}(X^2) = \sigma_1^2.$$

In particular, it does (in general) **not** hold true that

$$\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}\big((\sigma_1 \epsilon) \cdot (\sigma_2 \epsilon) \big)$$

for $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ (... and that's where your statistical approach fails).

Comment: If $X=\sigma_1 \varepsilon$ and $Y=\sigma_2\varepsilon$, $\varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$ i.e both random variables have the same souce of normal randomness (which above is the only Wiener process), then using the statistical approach $\mathbb{E}[XY]=\sigma_1 \sigma_2$ as expected. So why should it not work in the case above?

Comment: @fragile Note that the stochastic integral $\int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s$ equals $\sqrt{\int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds} \epsilon$ in **distribution**. If you take random variables $X$ and $X'$ which are equal in distribution and random variables $Y$ and $Y'$ which are also equal in distribution, then $$\mathbb{E}(XY) = \mathbb{E}(X' Y')$$ **fails** to hold.

Comment: Thanks. But let me apply this for the case above. Let $X = a\varepsilon ,Y = b\varepsilon ,\varepsilon \sim N(0,1)$ and let $X' = aZ,Y' = bZ,Z \sim N(0,1)$. That is I have $X \buildrel \Delta \over = X',Y \buildrel \Delta \over = Y'$. This trivially gives $\begin{array}{l}
\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[a\varepsilon b\varepsilon ] = ab\mathbb{E}[{\varepsilon ^2}] = ab\\
\mathbb{E}[X'Y'] = \mathbb{E}[aZbZ] = ab\mathbb{E}[{Z^2}] = ab
\end{array}$ so $\mathbb{E}[XY] = \mathbb{E}[X'Y']$. So the covariances are equal. How can I prove the statistical approach above is incorrect?

Comment: @fragile You do not seem to understand that there is a difference between "equal in distribution" and "equal in a  pointwise sense" There is no way that you are going to find a random variable $\epsilon \sim N(0,1)$ such that $$\int_0^t f(s) \, dW_s = \sqrt{\int_0^t f(s)^2 \, ds} \epsilon \quad \text{and} \quad \int_0^t g(s) \, dW_s = \sqrt{\int_0^t g(s)^2 \, ds} \epsilon$$ in a **pointwise sense**; these identities hold in distribution, but not pointwise.

Comment: thanks a lot. So in fact it does matter, how the normals are constructed. The pointwise sense point I missed before. Still, I can't fully say I understand the difference completely (for me a covariance of two perfectly correlated normals is just $1{\sigma _{{{{\mathop{\rm var}} }_1}}}{\sigma _{{{{\mathop{\rm var}} }_2}}}$, regardless of how the two normals were constructed. If I take $\mathbb{E}\left[ {\int\limits_0^T {adW(t)} \int\limits_0^T {bdW(t)} } \right]$ I get the result $abt$ regardless of which approach I use. So my last question is-under what condition are both approaches the same?

Comment: I don't think you understand what saz is saying, fragile... Your answer for the second approach is incorrect and you are making life hard for yourself by trying to compare a correct answer (first approach) to an incorrect answer (second approach). These two approaches are never going to be equal - because that would require equality in distribution and equality in path.

Comment: Let $w$ be a Wiener process and consider the processes $x_t = w_{T}-w_{t}$, $y_t =w_{T-t}$, where $0 \leq t \leq T < \infty$. It can be shown that $x$ and $y$ have the same distribution, i.e., $\mathbb{P}[x_t \leq a]=\mathbb{P}[y_t \leq a]$ but this does not mean that $x=y$, i.e., equality in distribution does not imply equality in path. Say that $(t,T)=(1,2)$, $(w_t,w_T)=(-1,4)$. Then $x_t=w_T-w_t=w_2-w_1=4+1=5$ and $y_t=w_{T-t}=w_{1}=-1$. Obviously $-1 \neq 5$.